# New install on EC2 rewrite issues

Tags: nginx, aws, amazon-web-services, loadbalancing

I've just finished installing 2.1.7 on an Ubuntu EC2 instance running Nginx behind a load balancer. SSL terminates at the load balancer with the EC2 instance serving HTTP only.

As close as I was able to discern putting "fastcgi_param HTTPS on;" in the correct Nginx location blocks is supposed to deal with the load balancer SSL termination issue. Though I will need to go back to that, as there seems to be more important problems.

When requesting ttps://www.(domain).com/ the site's blank page loads but all the script and link url's return 404. Here is an example:

> ttps://www.(domain).com/pub/static/version1496642016/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css

Note that removing "/pub" from the url does return the correct CSS file.

When requesting ttps://www.(domain).com/index.php the site's blank page loads and all the script and link url's load properly without the "/pub" folder in the url.

This is my nginix site configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name (domain).com *.(domain).com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload' always;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    return 301 https://www.(domain).com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.(domain).com;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/(domain).com;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

    fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;

    # Block Bad Bots (conf.d blacklist.conf & conf.d/blockips.conf)
    # Send 403 Forbidden or 444 Drop Connection
    if ($bad_bot) { return 444; }
    # Block Bad Referers
    # Send 403 Forbidden
    if ($bad_referer) { return 403; }
    if ($bad_urls1) { return 403; }
    if ($bad_urls2) { return 403; }
    if ($bad_urls3) { return 403; }
    if ($bad_urls4) { return 403; }
    if ($bad_urls5) { return 403; }
    if ($bad_urls6) { return 403; }
    # Block Snoopers
    # Send 444 Connection Closed Without Response
    if ($validate_client) { return 444;}

    # Log Exclusion
    set $logging 1;
    # Exclude user agents (conf.d/logexclusion.conf)
    if ( $log_ua = 0 ) {
        set $logging 0;
    }
    # Exclude CIDR Range IPs (conf.d/logexclusion.conf)
    if ( $log_ip = 0 ) {
        set $logging 0;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log timed_combined if=$logging;

    index index.php;
    autoindex off;
    charset UTF-8;
    error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;

    # Add HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) and Render/Frame Headers
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload' always;
    add_header X-UA-Compatible 'IE=edge,chrome=1';

    # PHP entry point for setup application
    location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;
        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    # PHP entry point for update application
    location ~* ^/update($|/) {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;

        location ~ ^/update/index.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # Deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /pub/ {
        location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
            deny all;
        }
        alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /static/ {
        # Uncomment the following line in production mode
        # expires max;

        # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
        location ~ ^/static/version {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }

        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }

        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/customer/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/downloadable/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/import/ {
        deny all;
    }

    # PHP entry point for main application
    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/xml+rss
        image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;

    # Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
    location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
        deny all;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run following query in database

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

or if you have already value for that path, then change it from **1** to **0**.

Then flush cache and deploy static content as follows.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: This was the solution. Unfortunately my reputation does not allow me to publicly up vote the answer yet. None the less, thank you Kishan!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you. You are welcome.